# What is a student seeking a Ph.D called?

Tags: terminology

A student seeking a bachelor's degree is an *undergraduate student*; a student seeking a master's degree is a *graduate student*. What would a student seeking a Ph.D. be called? Would he/she still be called a graduate student or is there a different term to be used?

Comment: They would also be a graduate student.

Comment: Your definition of _graduate student_ is wrong. A student who is admitted to study for **any** degree beyond the baccalaureate (Bachelor's level) is a _graduate student_. They have already graduated, that is. This includes Master's and Doctor's degrees. Special appellations are available for graduate students at medical and dental schools (_medical_ or _dental student_).

Answer (score 3):

Ph.D. candidate maybe.
I think it is OK.

Comment: "Doctoral" might also do although I wouldn't want to be too doctrinal on the matter.